# Ruby: Loop through multiple to return organized lists

Tags: ruby, list, sinatra, datamapper, relationship

I'm writing a web app that lets users browse through attractions in regions, states and countries. Currently I have the app set up in a way where attractions belong to regions, regions belong to states, and states belong to countries.

What I'm trying to do is write the view for a State. I'm trying to come up with a way to get lists of regions and the attractions in them, so something like

**STATE**

- Region 1

  - Attraction 1
  - Attraction 2
- Region 2

  - Attraction 3
  - Attraction 4

but I have been unable to come up with a way to do this that feels "right".

I'm using Sinatra and Datamapper with MySQL, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the states data :

```
@states=State.all
```

In the view (HAML) :

```
=@states.each do |state|
  %h6 state.name
  %ul
    =state.regions.each |region|
      %li
        #{region.name}
        %ul
          =region.attractions.each do |attraction|
            %li attraction.name
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Can't believe I couldn't think of it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are more concerned about the UI than the implementation. It'd be cool if you can use a real map with markers representing each attraction. Check out Google maps API to see if it fits your needs..